# Eclipse we-app Error using google cloud

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, attributes, version, xml-namespaces

Eclipse is returning a couple of quite frustrating errors.

attribute xmlns must be declared for element type web-app
attribute version must be declared for element type web-app

This is the source code for web.xml
I got it from following the instructions from this site.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ui_and_code

Here is also the code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Oracle Corporation//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>guestbook</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.guestbook.GuestbookServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>guestbook</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/guestbook</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>guestbook.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The errors occur on line 5. I'm not sure s to how to fix this problem. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the first 5 lines with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">
```

But your app will probably run properly anyway, so you can also disable that Eclipse warning.